# Visual Studio debugger is out of sync with my code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, debugging, mstest, visual-studio-2019

I modified some code and set a breakpoint, but when the debugger hits that breakpoint, it goes nuts and runs the old code anyway!

Here is the original code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new <see cref="CommaSeparatedValue"/> for the specified values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="values"></param>
public CommaSeparatedValue(params object[] values)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        if (value is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)value)
            {
                list.Add(Scrub(item));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(Scrub(value));
        }
    }

    _List = list;
}
```

And what I changed it to:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new <see cref="CommaSeparatedValue"/> for the specified values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="values"></param>
public CommaSeparatedValue(params object[] values)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        if (value is IEnumerable && !(value is string)) // !!! - I changed this line here
        {
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)value)
            {
                list.Add(Scrub(item));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(Scrub(value));
        }
    }

    _List = list;
}
```

I set the breakpoint on the line that I modified (checking for a string value) and when the debugger hits that line it ignores the part that I added and continues running into the "if" block even when the `value` variable is a string.

If it matters, this code is being run from a MSTest unit test.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you tried to see if your Visual Studio has any updates? I know mine acts weird sometimes if I haven't updated it in a while.

Comment: I have a feeling I have seen this behaviour when the project you are debugging is not being built after you have modified the code. Look in the Configuration Manager and make sure 'build' is checked.

Comment: Do a Clean, then Rebuild.

Comment: Can't reproduce the same issue in MsTest(.net core) project template. Please:1. Make sure you're in debug mode and don't check the Optimize code for debug mode.(Project=>Properties=>Build=>Optimize code) 2.Rebuild the project before you debug the test project in `test explorer`

Comment: @peterG aha, you're right - the unit test project was not part of the solution build! Why don't you go post your comment as an answer so this post can be resolved? :)

Comment: @ekolis It's not really enough to be an answer rather than a comment - but if you insist . . .

Comment: @peterG It answered my question so I think that qualifies it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when for some reason your project is not being built before you run it, so that the code the debugger is running is no longer the same as the source you are looking at. Look in the Configuration Manager and make sure 'Build' is checked for the configuration you're using.